# Java 8 Collections - Filtering on values in nested list

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I'm new to Java 8 and the Stream API.

If I have a list of Employee objects:

```
List<Employee> employees;

public class Employee {
    private String name;
    private List<Project> involvedInProjects;
}

public class Project {
    private int projectId;
}
```

I want to filter on employees beeing involved in certain projects, how would I go about doing this with the stream API in java 8?

Would it be easier if I had a Map where the key was an unique employeeID, instead of a List?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind modifying the list in place, you can use `removeIf` and the predicate you will give as parameter will check if the projects where an employee is involved does not match the given id(s).

For instance,

```
employees.removeIf(e -> e.getInvolvedInProjects().stream().anyMatch(p -> p.getProjectId() == someId));
```

If the list does not support the removal of elements, grab the stream from the `employees` list and filter it with the opposite predicate (in this case you could use `.noneMatch(p -> p.getProjectId() == someId)`) as in `removeIf` and collect the result using `Collectors.toList()`.

Comment: When using streams and filter, you need the *opposite* predicate as in `removeIf`. Besides that, it’s preferable to get the actual `Project` instance first and do a simple `getInvolvedInProjects() .contains(project)` test (assuming that `Project`s are either canonical or have a proper `equals` method, but everything else would be a questionable design)…

Comment: @Holger Thanks, don't know what's wrong with me today! Totally agree with your last point...

Answer (score 12):

So you can get access to the nested list inside of a stream operation and then work with that. In this case we can use a nested stream as our predicate for the filter

```
employees.stream().filter(
employee -> employee.involvedInProjects.stream()
.anyMatch(proj -> proj.projectId == myTargetId ))
```

This will give you a stream of all of the employees that have at least one project matching you targetId. From here you can operate further on the stream or collect the stream into a list with `.collect(Collectors.toList())`